# Error: Cannot find module 'pvutils' [Heroku]

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I've deployed a node js application on Heroku, installing this [verificac19-sdk library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/verificac19-sdk).

I've executed this app in local and It works properly.
But on Heroku, after the build, when the app starts appear this error and crashed.

This module it's not directely present in package.json, but I think it's a dependancy of verificac19 library.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "verificac19-sdk": "^0.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
```

**Heroku log error**

```
2021-11-23T23:06:58.053821+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-11-23T23:06:59.179410+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-11-23T23:06:59.322594+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-11-23T23:06:59.058770+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
2021-11-23T23:06:59.058789+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw err;
2021-11-23T23:06:59.058790+00:00 app[web.1]:   ^
2021-11-23T23:06:59.058790+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-11-23T23:06:59.058790+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'pvutils'
```

Comment: Have you run `yarn` or `npm` to install your dependencies locally and committed the lock file? Heroku uses the lock file if it is present.

Comment: @chri I have run npm. Yes, in the commit the lock file is present. Do you think that I should remove lock file from the commit, so Heroku installs alone all depemdencias?

Comment: You should generally _commit_ the lock file, but make sure it is fully up to date.

Comment: @chris can I check if it's up to date?

Comment: If you are using Yarn, try [`yarn install --check-files`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install#toc-yarn-install-check-files). With NPM I think you just `npm install` and see if the `package-lock.json` file changes. (And if it does, commit those changes.)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved installing `pvutils` manually, so it's present in `package.json` and then Heroku starts correctly.